# How do I identify a webmail service from an email address?

Tags: email, dns, web-scraping, webmail

If I have an email address, such as `doesnotexist@gmail.com` I can identify that it belongs to the gmail webmail service from the `gmail.com` domain name. There are also `googlemail.com` addresses which belong to the same service.

Is there a known list of domains belonging to popular email services?

E.g.

- Hotmail (hotmail.com, live.com..)
- Gmail (gmail.com, googlemail.com..)
- Yahoo (yahoo.com..)

Comment: If there isn't, then you could always turn this into CW and have people add the ones they know of in. Like I know sympatico.ca (sympatico.com too?) is under Hotmail, but I know of no list itself.

Answer (score 6):

[urlblacklist.com](http://urlblacklist.com) has a 'webmail' category that lists over 400 webmail domains. You can download is [here](http://urlblacklist.com/cgi-bin/commercialdownload.pl?type=download&file=bigblacklist) and the list is in under `bigblacklist.tar.gz\blacklists\webmail\domains`.

Its more targeted towards preventing access to those services though. For example it has:

- '`login.live.com`' but not '`live.com`'
- '`gmail.com`' but not '`googlemail.com`'

Hopefully its a good starting point though.

Comment: urlblacklist.com no longer exists